# How to add to arrays in models?

Tags: plugin-development, php, models, array, yii

I have a model that contains a bunch of storage arrays where I collect results from various services I have written.

```
class Shipper_ResultsModel extends BaseModel
{
```

shipping categories for debugging

```
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'service'               => array('type'=>AttributeType::Enum, 'values'=>['post','courier','free','cantShip','needsQuote']),
            'options'               => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'boxes'                 => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'postShippingItems'     => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'courierShippingItems'  => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'freeShippingItems'     => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'cantShippingItems'     => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
            'quoteShippingItems'    => array('type'=>AttributeType::Mixed,'default'=>[]),
        );
    }
```

Each of this `ShippingItems` arrays is intended to hold an array of Shipper_ShippingItem models.

My issue is in building these arrays, I create new items and add them like this:

```
            $shippingItem = Shipper_ShippingItemModel::populateModel($data);

            //build our arrays of items
            if($shippingClass=="Courier Only"){
                $results->courierShippingItems[] = $shippingItem;
            }
```

But this results in the following error:

```
PHP Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Craft\Shipper_ResultsModel::$courierShippingItems has no effect
```

I think this is because I am not using array objects as such but I have to say I've  got a little confused here and various syntax experiments have resulted in ignoble failures.

Some guidance as to the right way would be much appreciated (and am I right in using `AttributeType::Mixed` for these?)

(This is all for a mega shipping calculator for Craft Commerce, should that matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `'default'=>[]` isn't doing anything so it's probably not necessary.

If you wanted to force a single attribute to be of a specific model, you could use:

```
'courierShippingItems'  => array('type' => AttributeType::Mixed, 'model' => 'Shipper_ShippingItemModel');
```

Regardless, you'll want to use BaseModel's [setAttribute](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/BaseModel.php#L355) to do what you're trying to do and build your entire array up first before assigning it to the attribute.  Something like this:

```
$shippingItems[] = Shipper_ShippingItemModel::populateModel($data);

$results->setAttribute('courierShippingItems', $shippingItems);
```

Comment: Thanks Brad - I am now doing it like this, although simply building the array in a separate variable, and then assigning it directly at the end, rather than using setAttribute, appears to work fine as well.